# With Ubuntu 18.04, how can I have a hot corner that locks the computer?

Tags: gnome-shell, lock-screen

I want to have a **hot corner** that will immediately (and reliably) load my lock screen. Any suggestions?

Comment: xdotool can do this.. go through `man xdotool`

Comment: @PRATAP Could you please expand it to an answer?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For what it is worth:

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>  (Super is the Windows key on PC, or the command key <kbd>⌘</kbd> on Macs) locks your screen.

I always have the screen blanker off, but it still activates as I press these keys.

---

System Settings > Brightness & Lock:

Turn screen off when inactive for: Never.

Lock: ON
Lock screen after: 30 seconds.

[v] Require my password when waking from suspend.

Comment: It says nothing about the **hot corner** part, the feature OP is looking for.

Comment: Yes? And how come this would not be still a valid answer? Maybe OP didn't know about this.

Comment: Thanks @Hannu - you are correct in that I did not know about this. Makes the hot corners no longer needed

Comment: +1 for addressing the XY problem, though in spirit of SE perhaps the other answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: -1 for not answering the question asked.

Comment: @ReinierPost Hannu went above and beyond by answering the *real* problem instead of sticking to the information provided. It's risky if it turns out you're wrong, but since in this case it was exactly what OP wanted, hardly downvote worthy.

Comment: I disagree. This content is in here for you and me, not just for the OP. Questions and answers must match so we can effectively find the answers to our questions.

Comment: FWIW: I absolutely hate the display corner tricks in Windows, "Shutdown" being the top issue; hunting that one in a Virtual  machine that runs in a window is repulsive.

Comment: I find it a bit amusing how hard some people have to accept that there actually exists solutions to problems that might bring you outside what you might expect at first. WHY would you NOT include those as *valid* answers?

Answer (score 50):

First you need to install a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481) called **[CustomCorner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1037/customcorner/)** to be able to activate hot-corners.

Then open the extension's preferences and choose a corner, and select '*Run Command*'.
[image]

In the command box, use the following

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
gnome-screensaver-command --lock
```

if you have the `gnome-screensaver` package installed.

Answer (score 16):

For what it's worth:

In Kubuntu 18.04 (Ubuntu with the KDE 5 desktop), this is built in:

System Settings > Workspace - Desktop Behaviour > Screen Edges - each of the screen edges and corners can be set to various actions one of which is Lock screen.

Comment: This question is tagged as using Gnome, so I'm not sure why you answer this for KDE.

Comment: @Mast Why does it matter? Someone else might stumble upon this post because of its similarity and find it useful.